# Multiple custom field sets in one contact tab (not the main one)?

Tags: contacts, custom-fields

Drupal 7.59, CiviCRM 5.5.1, Shoreditch alpha24.

Within a contact you can display a custom field set as an additional tab (or on main tab). On the main tab you can have groups of fields, including custom ones. Is it possible to organise several custom field sets into an extra tab? Then each set of fields could be collapsible/expandable, neatly organised etc, rather than having a mess of fields in a tab.

Ideally not heavy on coding, not looking to heavily modify CRM at all just hoping there was a simple way I hadn't found. I could achieve with view/profile, but that would need extra work while I currently envisage users using CRM natively.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no way to show all the custom fields in a single tab. However you can show all the custom fields on the Summary tab for that you will need to update each custom group to use 'Inline' for 'Display Style'. There is an extension released for 5.5 which developed by Coleman called '[CONTACT LAYOUT EDITOR](https://civicrm.org/extensions/contact-layout-editor)' which allows you to rearrange the contact summary screen, Move the most important information to the top, Remove unnecessary stuff from the screen.

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: I'm curious if this question/answer from 2018 is still accurate -- does anyone know if there's anything new as a way to have multiple custom field sets on the same tab? From what I can see the Contact Layout Editor seems to only allow formatting on the summary tab, not on any other tabs.